# login to google with http POST

Tags: c#, asp.net

Think google have a limitation for user , so users have to login to download a file , I want to login to a site like google with http post and after that download a file .

how to login to  site like google with http POST ?

Comment: As usual it is illegal to log in to sites like google programmatically.

Comment: @zerkms: It's not welcomed - yes, but illegal... In which law? Which country law?

Comment: @VikciaR: it is illegal according to the sites TOS and the country laws the company is registered in.

Comment: @zerkms: TOS most of the time leads not to legal consequences, but to service termination. You can be sued only when you break something, make some harm, some illegal action. (TOS isn't legal rules, TOS is service rules) And in legal action nobody will talk about TOS breaking, there will be saying about which laws you breaked.

Comment: @zerkms: I see you are from Russia (we neighbours :-)) Did you see any law from Russia, which restrict web parsing? (I don't say about content steeling, just parsing)

Comment: its perfectly legal. I think OP is referring to google OAuth service. @zerkms: OP can download a file from docs for sure. its his account and so who has a problem?

Comment: @naveen: if he refers to oAuth - then fine, if he wants to imitate user actions during login (using form) - then it is illegal.

Comment: @VikciaR: google denies authorizing through form programmatically. It is in their TOS. Since it is an agreement between user and company - its violation can be moved to law field. I'm not professional lawyer, so don't you.

Comment: @zerkms: when in agreement isn't mentioned money, worst case is agreement termination.

Comment: @VikciaR: do you know that 100% or you just hope it is?

Comment: @zerkms: our flame is absolutely pointless. Have a nice day.

Comment: @VikciaR: yep, the best way is just to stop the discussion you're not enough competent in. Me either though ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use some pop or imap component to retrieve mail. For example [Open Pop .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/).

Answer (score 1):

Without providing more details about how this site handles authentication your question is impossible to answer. Just saying a *site like google* is not enough. For example Google provides an API for doing this.

Now let's imagine that this site uses cookies to track authenticated users. Here's an overview of the process involved. You could use the [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) property of a HttpWebRequest. So you will send a first request to the page allowing to authenticate by sending the username/password. The cookie container will then capture the authentication cookie and it will be sent on subsequent request to download the file.

And illustration with code:

```
var container = new CookieContainer();

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/login");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.CookieContainer = container;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    values["password"] = "secret";
    values["username"] = "someuser";
    writer.Write(values.ToString());
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // At this stage if authentication went fine the 
    // cookie container should have the authentication cookie
    // allowing to track the user
}

// Now let's send a second request to download the file
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/authenticated_resource");
request.CookieContainer = container;
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    // TODO: do something with the response
}
```

Comment: he might want the C# api which google don't provide(we have to write). same goes with facebook. why does all these big guys ignore us? (C#) :)

Comment: They simple want that you watch their adds :-)

Comment: @zerkms: long day? do you know that the project you are mentioning was last updated around an year back and the new graph api came within four months. check this out http://blog.codovations.com/2011/04/tutorial-post-data-on-facebook-company.html thats not official pal, its just an attempt at being official.

Answer (score 0):

It's called screen scraping.  You have to issue HTTP Requests, post form data in cases where you want to submit a form, and then parse the responses.  I use HtmlAgilityPack to make these tasks easier, but it won't do it all for you...

**Have a look here:**
http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/06/c-html-screen-scraping-part-1.html
http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/06/c-html-screen-scraping-part-2.html